# Use Radio button on Aura:Iteration

Tags: slds

I am trying to use a radio button on my component that returns a list of values. I have been able to create the table, and return a list of values. However, I can only select the first value in the list.

Here is the list:
[image]

Here is my component code:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_resizable-cols" id="mbdCommunications" role="grid">
<thead>
    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
        <th class="slds-text-align_right" scope="col" style="width:3.25rem;">
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-assistive-text" id="column-group-header" title="Choose a row to select" style="width:10%;">Choose a row to select.</div>
    </th>
    <th aria-label="Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</span>
                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-arrowdown">
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_xx-small" icon-name="arrowdown"/>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="slds-resizable">
                <input type="range" aria-label="Name column width" class="slds-resizable__input slds-assistive-text" id="cell-resize-handle-750" max="1000" min="20" tabindex="-1" />
                <span class="slds-resizable__handle">
                    <span class="slds-resizable__divider"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Email Body" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
            <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Email Body</span>
                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-arrowdown">
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_xx-small" icon-name="arrowdown"/>
                    </span>
                </div>
             </a>
             <div class="slds-resizable">
                <input type="range" aria-label="Account Name column width" class="slds-resizable__input slds-assistive-text" id="cell-resize-handle-751" max="1000" min="20" tabindex="-1" />
                <span class="slds-resizable__handle">
                    <span class="slds-resizable__divider"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.actorsOnInvestment}" var="actorsOnInvestment">
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <td class="slds-text-align_right" role="gridcell">
                <span class="slds-radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio-01" value="radio-01" name="options" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="radio-button-label-01 column-group-header" />
                    <label class="slds-radio__label" for="radio-01" id="radio-button-label-01">
                        <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                        <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-assistive-text">Select item 1</span>
                    </label>
                </span>
            </td>    
            <th scope="row" tabindex="0">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{#actorsOnInvestment.Name}" >{#actorsOnInvestment.Name}</div>
            </th>
            <td role="gridcell">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                     <textarea id="emailBody" class="slds-textarea" placeholder="Type Email Body"/>
                </div> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
</tbody>
```

What might I be missing?

Comment: Try changing name of 'var' from actorsOnInvestment to something else. Same name of items & var may have some conflict maybe.

Comment: Make sure your `name` attributes are all unique - best way to do this is preprocess or use an id as the name field.

Comment: Are you referring to the input type line?

Comment: yes that's the one `name="somethingunique"`

Comment: Made both changes and to no avail, still not working.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my answer, but you also want to make sure that the id is either unique for each one, or not supplied. I would just leave the id field blank, imo. That caused issues for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is with aura components? If so, you honestly shouldn't be using standard inputs, you should be using [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputRadio). Set the type to radio and provide an aura:id and name (add the index to the name). Make sure you're capturing the indexVar from the aura:iteration while you're at it. This will allow each one to be selected, not just the first. This is assuming that you want only one option in the list to be selectable.

For that first scenario, here is a demonstration:

```html
<aura:iteration items="{!v.actorsOnInvestment}" var="actorsOnInvestment" indexVar="index">
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
        <td class="slds-text-align_right" role="gridcell">
            <lightning:input aura:id="emailOption" type="radio" name="options" value="{!'radio' + index}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

In the controller, you would then search for all the radio inputs to find which ones were checked using component.find( 'emailOption' ). Iterate through the list, and for each one that was checked, find the accompanying textarea to get the email content. The textarea id should match the value of the radio input. Since we have value="{!'radio' + index}" for the input, then for the textarea, set the id as id="{!'radio' + index}". Then just use document.getElementById to get the textarea that matches the radio button and then get the text.

---

If you instead want to be able to select multiple people, I would suggest some other solutions. You can either use a lightning:input of type="toggle" for each one and then use the same aura:id, value, textarea option as above, or you can use the lightning:input (if you want the same look), but with different names for each input. In that case, you will need to wrap the inputs in a span with an onclick action that will uncheck the input if it is checked. You can try giving the span an Id that matches the value of the checkbox, or use another method to get the child input. Either ways, you will need to use some clever method to allow the input to be deselected (by default, you can't deselect radio inputs directly, you have to select another one in the same name group). The names should be dynamic, like the value (example: name="{!'emailOptionInput' + index}"). If you would like some more detailed code examples for these two options, let me know and I can add them to the answer.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for all of the information on this!!!

Comment: You're welcome @JPBlonshine. If it doesn't work for you, just let me know. :)